# Delete row based on specific datetime and conditions columnwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Hi all I'm trying to delete rows based on a few conditions and needed some help. I have a dataframe with this structure, assuming there are more columns:

```
date     city    col_a    col_b    col_c ... 
1/22/20  la      0        0        0
1/23/20  la      0        0        0
1/24/20  la      0        0        0
1/22/20  ny      3        0        1
1/23/20  ny      0        1        1
1/24/20  ny      0        1        0
1/22/20  sf      0        0        0
1/23/20  sf      0        2        0
1/24/20  sf      2        0        0
.
.
.
```

I would like to scan the dataframe based on the `city` and the latest date for that city, and remove that entire set of rows if the latest date for that city has `col_a`, `col_b` AND `col_c` values of `0`. Assume `city` column will be unique, and I have to scan every unique value. So resulting dataframe should be:

```
date     city    col_a    col_b    col_c ... 
1/22/20  ny      3        0        1
1/23/20  ny      0        1        1
1/24/20  ny      0        1        0
1/22/20  sf      0        0        0
1/23/20  sf      0        2        0
1/24/20  sf      2        0        0
.
.
.
```

I'm assuming this is a groupby problem but not sure how to get latest date and delete entirety of the rows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `transform` + `all`

```
df = df[~df.filter(like='col').eq(0).all(1).groupby(df.city).transform(all)]
Out[389]: 
      date city  col_a  col_b  col_c
3  1/22/20   ny      3      0      1
4  1/23/20   ny      0      1      1
5  1/24/20   ny      0      1      0
6  1/22/20   sf      0      0      0
7  1/23/20   sf      0      2      0
8  1/24/20   sf      2      0      0
```